# Can one define a chunk grammar for OpenNLP?

Tags: nltk, opennlp

NLTK supports the defining of a chunk grammar. For example, I can define a chunk grammar for a noun phrase (NP) like this:

```
grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}"
```

I don't see a way to tell OpenNLP what a noun phrase is. I imagine I could walk the parse tree but that seems painful.